# How to fix: bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin SSLPeerUnverifiedException error

Tags: jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-api

I am setting up Bitbucket pull request builder plugin on my jenkins instance with Bitbucket URL = https://bitbucket.org. But, https request to bitbucket throws the SSLPeerUnverifiedException error. How can I solve this? Is there an option to Ignore ssl certificates?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:440) 
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:257) 
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:115) 
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:156) 
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:714) at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:394) 
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:178) 
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:404) at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:330) at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.ApiClient.send(ApiClient.java:180) 
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.ApiClient.get(ApiClient.java:126) 
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.server.ServerApiClient.getAllValues(ServerApiClient.java:121) 
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.server.ServerApiClient.getPullRequests(ServerApiClient.java:37) 
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketRepository.getTargetPullRequests(BitbucketRepository.java:117) 
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketPullRequestsBuilder.run(BitbucketPullRequestsBuilder.java:37) 
at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.BitbucketBuildTrigger$TriggerRunnable.run(BitbucketBuildTrigger.java:402) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

I expect the plugin to ignore SSL verification and talk to Stash. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: I'm interested, too.